# Java equivalent of .NET's System.Xml.Schema classes?

Tags: java, .net, xml, xsd, shared-libraries

The .NET Framework exposes a rather useful set of classes as part of the [System.Xml.Schema namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.schema.xmlschema.aspx).

Among other things, classes such as XmlSchema and XmlSchemaElement provide a useful API for defining/writing and parsing/reading/traversing XML schema files.

Does an equivalent library exist for Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tools to accomplish this are there, but I don't think there's anything specific like that in Java.  What I would do is run JAXB on the XML Schema schema (http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema), which will generate Java classes corresponding to the XSD constructs.  Then you can use those to read/write XML schemas, and validate against the XML Schema schema.